# How to move fabricjs object created in nextjs useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

when I create a fabric canvas in a useEffect() it doesn't allow me to move the added images, but if I create it elsewhere (subject to useState asynchrony issues) it does allow me to move normally. The code that doesn't work, but is what I need:

```
export default function Home(){
 const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState();

 useEffect(() => {
  setCanvas(new fabric.Canvas('canvas', selectable: true, renderOnAddRemove: false}));
 }, []);

 const addImage = () => {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Image("/myImage.png").renderAll();
 }

 return(
  <>
   <canvas id="canvas" />
   <button onClick(addImage)>Add Image </button>
  </>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arise from the fact that next adds an addictional canvas-container in the HTML structure.

[double canvas container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDtmh.png)
To prevent this you can check if the canvas is already initialized like so:

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const FabricTest = () => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const fabricCanvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Only initialize the Fabric canvas if it hasn't been initialized yet
        if (!fabricCanvasRef.current) {
            fabricCanvasRef.current = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
                height: 800,
                width: 800,
                backgroundColor: 'pink',
            });
        }
    }, []);

    const addRect = () => {
        const rect = new fabric.Rect({
            height: 280,
            width: 200,
            fill: 'yellow',
            selectable: true,
            hasControls: true,
        });
        fabricCanvasRef.current.add(rect);
        fabricCanvasRef.current.renderAll();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={addRect}>Rectangle</button>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default FabricTest;
```